# Change sort order of contacts

Tags: contacts

I have a HTC Legend with Android 2.2. My contacts usually have first name and last name filled in. The ordering and display consists of `<first name> <last name>`. Since I know most of my clients by last name primarily, that doesn't really help.

I know of the combobox when editing a contact name where I can switch that. However, the last time I received an update of Android that was changed back to `<first name> <last name>` for all contacts. Obviously I want to avoid that.

Is there a way to change the display and hopefully the sorting order to `<last name> <first name>` that survives updates and whatnot?

Comment: Try using a third party contact program? A light contact manager I'd recommend would be: [Exdialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modoohut.dialer)

Comment: @thunderror Yeah, I thought about using other programs, but IMHO it would be better if I could make the installed default app work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In the Contacts app (or Phone app if you don't have a direct link in the launcher) press the 'Menu' button then select 'Display Options'.

You should find two categories to choose from, 'Sort list by' and 'View contact names by'.

Comment: I don't have that :( All I have is (translated into English): Contacts, Call list, Shorcuts, Phone Setup, Hints. In case you are wondering, Hints doesn't really show any hint and Setup doesn't provide anything remotely close.

Comment: Go to the Contacts tab, then press the Menu button and see if you have the option. It might also be under 'Settings'.

Comment: I have checked all Menu-screens in all tabs and I can't find anything. So I guess somebody turned off that feature, even though it's not clear to me why that makes any sense.